# Android - Appending text on top of other text in a TextView

Tags: android

I am appending symbols to a TextView programmatically at different time intervals. Is there a way to add text on top of these symbols at the same time? For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    tv.append(Integer.toString(i));
}
```

This would give me `0 1 2 3 4` inside my TextView, but is there a way to also add something on top of those numbers, such as:

```
a b c d e
0 1 2 3 4
```

where the letters are smaller than the numbers

Comment: Simply take two TextView

Comment: What happens when the first TextView goes onto a new line though?

Comment: As you told in the question you are appending on the time interval so that you should not always run loop from starting

Comment: I agree with manifest, and as an addition to his comment, it's also imposible to have to different sized text in one textView as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If the symbol is 3x as long as the character I want to place on top of it, then how would 2 TextViews accommodate for that? i.e. If the first TextView went onto the next line, wouldn't the second TV (on top) be 'left behind'? The characters on top will always be 1 character, but the symbols may be variable in length

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] another = new String [] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
String top = String.join("", another);    //abcde
tv.setText(top +"\n" + tv.getText());
tv.setMaxLines(2); // you might change 2 to 20 or whatever
```